# Reverse Proxy on Apache same domain different path

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, domain, reverse-proxy

Im new for the reverse proxy with Apache servers and I need to redirect my site to my web application. Here is the plan: I have that `sub.domain.com` that I want to redirect client to files under `xampp/htdocs/mysite`. Also I have that `sub.domain.com/endpoint` to redirect client to `http://localhost:8080/mywebapp`. Is it possible and if it is then how? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have three entries that match the *.80 AND the ServerName/ServerAlias (dashboard...). I think Apache is ignoring the second (which has the Proxy definition in it)  and third. .

Answer (score 0):

Here are the entries to set up the proxy to another port

```
ProxyPass /endpoint http://sub.domain.com:8080/mywebapp
ProxyPassReverse /endpoint http://sub.domain.com:8080/mywebapp
```

You could skip the /endpoint path and use a servername (host header) to do the same thing:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName mywebapp
    ServerAlias mywebapp.domain.com



     ProxyPass / http://sub.domain.com:8080/mywebapp
     ProxyPassReverse / http://sub.domain.com:8080/mywebapp


</VirtualHost>
```

Your Config file has multiple entries that match on both the address/port and Servername/ServerAlias. I think apache is ignoring the second two.  More on matching in the [Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/details.html)

Comment: it is not pretty simple and this does not work unfotunately. I tried that but both sub.domain.com and sub.domain.com/mywebapp directs browser to mywebapp

Comment: Im using vhost to serve my static web site under xampp/htdocs/mysite. Consider that please.

Comment: Perhaps you could add the portion your .conf file for the vhost. Also, what is in the error_log? BTW, Didn't mean anything by the "simple" comment.

Comment: you're right my bad here it is im editing and adding my vhost file

Comment: Thanks.  For safety, you may want to anonymize that a bit.